# how to read the output in c++

Tags: c++

I am solving a codechef problem. I have to ask Q queries (which I would have to print) and for every query computer would give me an output which I would have to save to use for another query. The problem statement states:

> For each test case, you may ask queries. To ask a query, print a line >containing the character 'Q', a space and two space-separated integers >x0 and y0 (0≤x0,y0≤109). Then, you should read a line containing a >single integer. If this integer is non-negative, it denotes the answer >to your query. Otherwise, it means that you exceeded the limit on the >number of queries, the coordinates you printed are invalid or some >other error occured.
>   When you have found the secret rectangle, you should print a line >containing the character 'A', a space and four space-separated integers >xl, yl, xu and yu. Then, you should read a single line containing one >integer, which is 1 if your answer was correct or negative if it was wrong.

How do I save output given from one query as input for another?

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong when you tried it?

Comment: I don't know how to read the output. There seems to be no source on the net where I could find to read the output.

Comment: Typically such tasks assume that you read from standard input and write to standard output unless stated otherwise.

Comment: Ok thanks @ Öö Tiib

Answer (score 1):

Normally these kind of challenges assume you use stdin for your input and stdout for your output. In cpp you can do

```
#include <iostream>
```

And use the " <<" operator on std::cout (output) and the ">>" operator for std::cin (input) 
Example below :

```
std::cout << "your output;
```